# Regex to block domains in url field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to block certain domains from input url field, i'm using jQuery Validation plugin, i've created a custom method only thing I can't figure out is the regex, it is driving me crazy.

```
$.validator.addMethod("customurl",
function(value, element) {
        return /^([\w-.]+@(?!facebook\.com)(?!twitter\.com)(?!instagram\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(value);
},

"Social links not allowed"
);
```

current regex blocks email addresses ending with those domains, but i want to block the urls, e.g:

https://www.facebook.com/username

https://facebook.com/username

http://facebook.com/username

Comment: Can you not try something like `return value.indexOf('facebook') === -1`

Comment: Does the regex need to still block email address ending with those domains, or do you want to block only the urls?

Comment: @Adam only the urls

Comment: Well thats just a simple regex command. If you don't know how to use regex use this simple tutorial: https://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators

Answer (score 0):

I would just add another regex test using:

```
/https?\:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/(.*)/
```

Which might look something like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customurl",
function(value, element) {
   var emailTest = /^([\w-.]+@(?!facebook\.com)(?!twitter\.com)(?!instagram\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(value);
   var urlTest = /https?\:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/(.*)/.test(value);
   return !emailTest && !urlTest;
});
```

Comment: how can i add other domains (instagram and twitter) in the urlTest?

Comment: isnt `[\w-.]` the same as  just `.`?